# TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined, coming from a mocked function

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I'm writting a component test using Jest and Enzyme.

The tested component has uses an imported static methods of a class named Service, which dispatches directly to the store.

The component itself, calls two of the `Service` class elements right in the `componentDidMount`, but also in the other parts of the component:

```js
    @connect(
        (state) => ({
            feedback: getFeedback(state),
            reportsLeft: getReportsLeft(state),
            reported: getReports(state),
            newRecordsLeft: getNewRecordsLeft(state),
        }),
    )
    class Feedback extends React.Component<IFeedbackProps> {
        componentDidMount() {
            Service.updateReportsLeft(); //static async
            Service.updateNewRecordsLeft(); //static async
        }

        getCount(elementsLeft?: number): string {
            return elementsLeft === 0 ? 'Done' : `${elementsLeft} left`;
        }

        handleShowNext = (e: Event) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            Service.goToNextReport(); //static
        };

        renderShowNext() {
            const {reported} = this.props;
            const buttonText = 'Go to next';
            const {reportsLeft} = this.props;
            // @ts-ignore
            return reportsLeft > 0 ? <a href="#" onClick={this.handleShowNext}>{buttonText} </a> : null;
        }

        render() {
            const {reportsLeft, newRecordsLeft} = this.props;
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>Feedback: {this.getCount(reportsLeft)} {this.renderShowNext()}</p>
                    <p>New: {this.getCount(newRecordsLeft)} </p>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default Feedback;
```

I've tried mocking the four class methods with a simple mock, and later attempted to test even the simpliest `toBe` element on the component:

```js
    function setup() {
    //Also tested an approach with the function contents simply loading before the `describe` methods
        const
            testReportsLeft: number = 447,
            testNewRecordsLeft: number = 778,
            testFeedback = null,
            testReported = null;

        const props: IFeedbackProps = {
            reportsLeft: testReportsLeft,
            feedback: testFeedback,
            reported: testReported,
            newRecordsLeft: testNewRecordsLeft,
        };

        jest.mock('Services/service', () => ({
                goToNextReport: jest.fn(),
                updateReportsLeft: jest.fn(),
                updateNewRecordsLeft: jest.fn(),
                getCurrentState: jest.fn(),
            })
        );

        const feedback = shallow(<Feedback {...props} />);

        return feedback;
    }

    describe('Feedback', () => {
        describe('component view tests', () => {
            it('should render a div', () => {
                const feedback = setup();

                //This test is wrong in this part, I know. But for now its the reaching of this point that causes issues :/
                expect(feedback).toBe('div');
            })
        })
    });
```

However, upon running the test I get an error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

The errors trace goes as follows:

```
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/store/reducers.ts
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/store/index.ts
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/services/service.ts:41:31
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/sidebar/feedback.tsx:34:51
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/sidebar/_test_/feedback.spec.tsx:27:43)
```

So, as you can see, the path goes right back into the reducers. This is something I hoped to avoid, thus have added the mock for the functions.

I'm not sure what could be wrong with this code, and the internet is slowly stopping to have any idea on what could be wrong.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Also, if the resources provided are not enough, please let me know.

The JEST version is `21.2.1`. Unfortunately I am not able to change it (the version) due to the package being closely connected to another package I'm using.

Comment: Do you have a repo to test the issue?

Comment: add your reducers.ts file, you're trying to do something.products where something is undefined

Answer (score 2):

Try to check for lower version of The JEST version is 21.2.1

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined

You can check with below files set included or not

```
...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/store/reducers.ts
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/store/index.ts
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/services/service.ts:41:31
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/sidebar/feedback.tsx:34:51
 ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/sidebar/_test_/feedback.spec.tsx:27:43)
```

Here you can check with this below file

> ...Resources/public/js/admin-react-js/store/reducers.ts

Add this file and get run once again , so that your error undefined will get short out!!!!!!!!

Comment: @sugansoft My Jest package is sort of dependant on another package and I cant change the versions that easily.
I'm not sure what do you mean by checking if a file set is included. Could you elaborate?

Comment: dependant on another package.. so have you checked in another package? where this files set are included or not like tat?

Comment: @sugansoft Hi. Pardon the late reply and thanks for respondin. I'm sorry but I'm still confused here. I've tried importing the `reducers` file, but it did not result in anything. The package is dependant on `liform-react@0.9.0` and I really can't do any much touching around it. 

Might be due to my lame English but I do not understand what do you mean by checking whether a file is included. If you could, please explain it to me in a way even a chimpanzee would comprehend :P